# Kubernetes NFS storage class - where is the persistent data located?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, nfs, nfsclient

I'm testing with PostgreSQL in Kubernetes and I installed Kubegres as in the [official instructions](https://www.kubegres.io/doc/getting-started.html) with a single exception: I defined my own NFS storage class and 2 persistence volumes.

And everything works perfectly:

- I have 2 pods(primary and secondary), if I create a table on a pod the table is synchronized on the second pod.
- If I restart all the Kubernetes cluster nodes(the control-plane and all workers) I can still find my data so I have persistence.

The problem is that I can't find the data where is supposed to be, seems like a stupid question... but is not in 192.168.88.3/caidoNFS as the storage class is configured.
I mounted 192.168.88.3/caidoNFS on another machine and this folder is empty. So something is wrong or I'm missing something essential.

The storage class is:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: caido-nfs
provisioner: caido.ro/caido-nfs
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
  server: 192.168.88.3
  path: /caidoNFS
  readOnly: "false"
```

I have 2 Persistence Volumes that have 500Mi - exactly the size requested by the Persistent Volume Claims:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: caido-pv1
  labels:
    type: nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: caido-nfs
  capacity:
    storage: 500Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data1"


apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: caido-pv2
  labels:
    type: nfs
spec:
  storageClassName: caido-nfs
  capacity:
    storage: 500Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data2"
```

If I run **"kubectl get pod,statefulset,svc,configmap,pv,pvc -o wide"** this is the output:

```
NAME                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP              NODE                NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/mypostgres-1-0   1/1     Running   1          105m   192.168.80.3    kubernetesworker1   <none>           <none>
pod/mypostgres-2-0   1/1     Running   1          79m    192.168.80.66   kubernetesworker2   <none>           <none>

NAME                            READY   AGE    CONTAINERS     IMAGES
statefulset.apps/mypostgres-1   1/1     105m   mypostgres-1   postgres:14.1
statefulset.apps/mypostgres-2   1/1     79m    mypostgres-2   postgres:14.1

NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE    SELECTOR
service/kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP    5d5h   <none>
service/mypostgres           ClusterIP   None         <none>        5432/TCP   79m    app=mypostgres,replicationRole=primary
service/mypostgres-replica   ClusterIP   None         <none>        5432/TCP   73m    app=mypostgres,replicationRole=replica

NAME                             DATA   AGE
configmap/base-kubegres-config   7      105m
configmap/kube-root-ca.crt       1      5d5h

NAME                         CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE   VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolume/caido-pv1   500Mi      RWO            Retain           Bound    default/postgres-db-mypostgres-1-0   caido-nfs               79m   Filesystem
persistentvolume/caido-pv2   500Mi      RWO            Retain           Bound    default/postgres-db-mypostgres-2-0   caido-nfs               74m   Filesystem

NAME                                               STATUS   VOLUME      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE    VOLUMEMODE
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-db-mypostgres-1-0   Bound    caido-pv1   500Mi      RWO            caido-nfs      105m   Filesystem
persistentvolumeclaim/postgres-db-mypostgres-2-0   Bound    caido-pv2   500Mi      RWO            caido-nfs      79m    Filesystem
```

The description of my master PostgreSQL pod with the command "**kubectl describe pod mypostgres-1**" is:

```
Name:             mypostgres-1-0
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             kubernetesworker1/192.168.88.71
Start Time:       Thu, 22 Jun 2023 07:07:17 +0000
Labels:           app=mypostgres
                  controller-revision-hash=mypostgres-1-6f46f6f669
                  index=1
                  replicationRole=primary
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mypostgres-1-0
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 910d046ac8b269cd67a48d8334c36a6d8849ba34ca2161403101ba507856e339
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.80.12/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.80.12/32
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.80.12
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.80.12
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/mypostgres-1
Containers:
  mypostgres-1:
    Container ID:  cri-o://d3196998458acec1797f12279c00e8e58366764e57e0ad3b58f5617a85c7d421
    Image:         postgres:14.1
    Image ID:      docker.io/library/postgres@sha256:043c256b5dc621860539d8036d906eaaef1bdfa69a0344b4509b483205f14e63
    Port:          5432/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      -c
      config_file=/etc/postgres.conf
      -c
      hba_file=/etc/pg_hba.conf
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 22 Jun 2023 07:07:17 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       exec [sh -c exec pg_isready -U postgres -h $POD_IP] delay=60s timeout=15s period=20s #success=1 #failure=10
    Readiness:      exec [sh -c exec pg_isready -U postgres -h $POD_IP] delay=5s timeout=3s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      POD_IP:                          (v1:status.podIP)
      PGDATA:                         /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:              <set to the key 'superUserPassword' in secret 'mypostgres-secret'>        Optional: false
      POSTGRES_REPLICATION_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'replicationUserPassword' in secret 'mypostgres-secret'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/primary_create_replication_role.sh from base-config (rw,path="primary_create_replication_role.sh")
      /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/primary_init_script.sh from base-config (rw,path="primary_init_script.sh")
      /etc/pg_hba.conf from base-config (rw,path="pg_hba.conf")
      /etc/postgres.conf from base-config (rw,path="postgres.conf")
      /var/lib/postgresql/data from postgres-db (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-tlgnh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  postgres-db:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  postgres-db-mypostgres-1-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  base-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      base-kubegres-config
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-tlgnh:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  56s   default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/3 nodes are available: 3 No preemption victims found for incoming pod..
  Normal   Scheduled         54s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mypostgres-1-0 to kubernetesworker1
  Normal   Pulled            54s   kubelet            Container image "postgres:14.1" already present on machine
  Normal   Created           54s   kubelet            Created container mypostgres-1
  Normal   Started           54s   kubelet            Started container mypostgres-1
```

The message "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims" appears even if I have a Persistent Volume created and bound. Maybe this error appears because of some initial timeout? This is the output of "**kubectl describe pvc postgres-db-mypostgres-1-0**":

```
Name:          postgres-db-mypostgres-1-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  caido-nfs
Status:        Bound
Volume:        caido-pv1
Labels:        app=mypostgres
               index=1
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      500Mi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       mypostgres-1-0
Events:        <none>
```

To summarize there are 2 questions:

- where is the persistent data located? I accessed \192.168.88.3\caidoNFS on a Windows and I mounted it in a Linux fstab but the folder is empty.
  //192.168.88.3/caidoNFS     /mnt/nfs        cifs   username=admin,dom=mydomain,password=...#  0        0
- why does the message "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims" appears if the PVC is bound?

Comment: 2 things are happening to your cluster that make the scheduling of the pods not succeed: The first is related to your cluster not being able to bind the pod to a PV that fulfills the request created by the PVC. **You may need to manually provision a PV or install the correct CSI driver for your cloud provider**. The second probably means your cluster is out of capacity or the worker nodes are unschedulable. **You may need to scale up your resources**.

Comment: But both pods have the status = "Running", which means they passed the scheduling phase and both of the PVCs have the status bound, I already manually provisioned 2 PVs as described in my post(I created the YAML's for caido-pv1 and caido-pv2). The PV's status is also bound.

Answer (score 1):

I found my data, it was in /mnt/data1 and /mnt/data2 on every worker node. I guess the NFS failed for some unknown reason and the system created a local storage on every worker node.
I probably didn't configure the NFS as I should, I'll read more about this.